# A new on-the-fly variable from ng-repeat is not visible outside the ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I have a label showing amount of filtered items in my code like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Filter: <input ng-model='filterExpr'><button ng-click='items.push("car")'>Add sth to the list</button>
        <button ng-click='items.splice(items.length-1,1)'>minus sth from the list</button>
<hr>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in filtered = (items | filter:filterExpr)'>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
<hr>    
Filtered list has {{filtered.length}} items
```

Like sample here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/Nk8qy/3/)

But after I put **ng-repeat** section to the one of **ng-switch** view it seems like on-the-fly variable **filtered** from ng-repeat is not visible anymore outside of **ng-switch**.

```
 <div ng-switch on="viewType.value">
  <div ng-switch-default>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='item in filtered = (items | filter:filterExpr)'>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Like here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy1odgf5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens because `ng-switch` creates its own scope. You can get around it by using `$parent` inside the switch.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in $parent.filtered = (items | filter:filterExpr)'>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```